# How to set number of copies from textbox to print To ptinter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

**I'm using this code for printing to printer to print reportviewer without showing dialoge,
but I can't set the number of copies to print
I need a textbox or numericUpDown or anything to put the number of copies**

> using System;
> using System.IO;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Globalization;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Drawing.Imaging;
> using System.Drawing.Printing;
> using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Collections.Specialized;
> using System.Diagnostics;
> using System.ComponentModel;
> using System.Data;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace NewLabelPrinter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ReportPrintDocument will print all of the pages of a ServerReport or LocalReport.
    /// The pages are rendered when the print document is constructed.  Once constructed,
    /// call Print() on this class to begin printing.
    /// </summary>
    class AutoPrintCls : PrintDocument
    {
        private PageSettings m_pageSettings;
        private int m_currentPage;
        private List<Stream> m_pages = new List<Stream>();

        public AutoPrintCls(ServerReport serverReport)
            : this((Report)serverReport)
        {
            RenderAllServerReportPages(serverReport);
        }

        public AutoPrintCls(LocalReport localReport)
            : this((Report)localReport)
        {
            RenderAllLocalReportPages(localReport);
        }

        private AutoPrintCls(Report report)
        {
            // Set the page settings to the default defined in the report
            ReportPageSettings reportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();

            // The page settings object will use the default printer unless
            // PageSettings.PrinterSettings is changed.  This assumes there
            // is a default printer.
            m_pageSettings = new PageSettings();
            m_pageSettings.PaperSize = reportPageSettings.PaperSize;
            m_pageSettings.Margins = reportPageSettings.Margins;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (Stream s in m_pages)
                {
                    s.Dispose();
                }

                m_pages.Clear();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBeginPrint(e);

            m_currentPage = 0;
        }

        protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPrintPage(e);

            Stream pageToPrint = m_pages[m_currentPage];
            pageToPrint.Position = 0;

            // Load each page into a Metafile to draw it.
            using (Metafile pageMetaFile = new Metafile(pageToPrint))
            {
                Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                        e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                        e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                        e.PageBounds.Width,
                        e.PageBounds.Height);

                // Draw a white background for the report
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

                // Draw the report content
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, adjustedRect);

                // Prepare for next page.  Make sure we haven't hit the end.
                m_currentPage++;
                e.HasMorePages = m_currentPage < m_pages.Count;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
        {
            e.PageSettings = (PageSettings)m_pageSettings.Clone();
        }

        private void RenderAllServerReportPages(ServerReport serverReport)
        {
            try
            {
                string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

                // Generating Image renderer pages one at a time can be expensive.  In order
                // to generate page 2, the server would need to recalculate page 1 and throw it
                // away.  Using PersistStreams causes the server to generate all the pages in
                // the background but return as soon as page 1 is complete.
                NameValueCollection firstPageParameters = new NameValueCollection();
                firstPageParameters.Add("rs:PersistStreams", "True");

                // GetNextStream returns the next page in the sequence from the background process
                // started by PersistStreams.
                NameValueCollection nonFirstPageParameters = new NameValueCollection();
                nonFirstPageParameters.Add("rs:GetNextStream", "True");

                string mimeType;
                string fileExtension;


                Stream pageStream = serverReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, firstPageParameters, out mimeType, out fileExtension);



                // The server returns an empty stream when moving beyond the last page.
                while (pageStream.Length > 0)
                {
                    m_pages.Add(pageStream);

                    pageStream = serverReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, nonFirstPageParameters, out mimeType, out fileExtension);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("possible missing information ::  " + e);
            }
        }

        private void RenderAllLocalReportPages(LocalReport localReport)
        {
            try
            {
                string deviceInfo = CreateEMFDeviceInfo();

                Warning[] warnings;

                localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, out warnings);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error :: " + e);
            }
        }

        private Stream LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(
            string name,
            string extension,
            Encoding encoding,
            string mimeType,
            bool willSeek)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_pages.Add(stream);

            return stream;
        }

        private string CreateEMFDeviceInfo()
        {
            PaperSize paperSize = m_pageSettings.PaperSize;
            Margins margins = m_pageSettings.Margins;

            // The device info string defines the page range to print as well as the size of the page.
            // A start and end page of 0 means generate all pages.
            return string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage><EndPage>0</EndPage><MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop><MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft><MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight><MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom><PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight><PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth></DeviceInfo>",
                ToInches(margins.Top),
                ToInches(margins.Left),
                ToInches(margins.Right),
                ToInches(margins.Bottom),
                ToInches(paperSize.Height),
                ToInches(paperSize.Width));
        }

        private static string ToInches(int hundrethsOfInch)
        {
            double inches = hundrethsOfInch / 100.0;
            return inches.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";
        }
    }
}
```

> this is the Print button

```
private void btnPrint_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AutoPrintCls autoprintme = new AutoPrintCls(reportViewer1.LocalReport);
    
                autoprintme.Print();
            }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.copies?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 have you read the documents?

Comment: Yes but I'm a beginner and I didn't know how to use the code in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `btnPrint_Click_1` event can refer to the following code:

```
private void btnPrint_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoPrintCls autoprintme = new AutoPrintCls(reportViewer1.LocalReport);
        autoprintme.PrinterSettings.Copies = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);
        autoprintme.Print();        
    }
```